# Github pull request from a personnal repo to an organization repo

Tags: git, github

Despite this seems a simple problem, I did not find any tutorial on this or answers that match my situation.

I developed some code on a repo under my personal github account. This was latter forked by a colleague. He produces work, and occasionally PR to my repo. Working in a team, we recently decided to switch to an *organization*, so several users can contribute. The reasons are that we want to avoid disruptions when people join/leave the team, and we want the "official" (and stable) repo to be the one of the team and not one of an individual.

The way I understand the workflow is: we all have a fork of the repo in our personal accounts, relatively up-to-date. If someone makes a change, they will push it to their own repo. When they are ready (this can be later) they PR to the organization one. My problem is that I cannot figure out this last step.

I created the repo under the organization using github cli:

```
gh repo create team-name/repo-name
```

and pushed my local (up to date) version into this:

```
git push --mirror https://github.com/team-name/repo-name.git
```

Now I worked on my local version, and pushed to my own remote. But I cannot figure out how to make a PR to the organization repo to reflect the changes. It does not appear in the gihub web interface, and I can't understand how to write the pr request in github CLI anyway... I feel like I misunderstood something. Maybe I should have forked the team repo, but then don't I end up with twice the same repo (or do I have to delete my own first)? Or maybe I need to change the remote?

Maybe this comes from a poor understanding of what the workflow should be in such situation. But I'd be happy if someone explains to me how to achieve that, and where I went wrong.